# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Tags: oracle, java

I'm trying to run a webservice client on jdk1.5 and gives me the following error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details: what kind of webservice client. Maybe some code post would help.

Comment: the web service client is for sending sms (text messages) and its intended to be used after loading the classes to Oracle and for that reason I am compelled to use JDK 1.5

Comment: Any Suggestions will be indeed appreciated

Comment: I don't fully understand your scenario, what I can say for sure is that the provider is not on the classpath.

Comment: I am using NetBeans IDE 7.3, please advice if this error refers to any jar files that are required and missing

Comment: I have the error when working with jax-ws in Android. Is there any solution of it in Android?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that on your path you can find also the jar containing the class `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`. I checked what jar might be needed and [here](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl) you can see the jars containing the given class. Any of them might help you.

Comment: how we can identify which jar version will be compatible with JDK 1.5

Comment: In the link provided there is also this information: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl [1362 bytes, jvm >= 1.5 ]
jaxws-rt-2.0EA3.jar
class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl [4883 bytes, jvm >= 1.5 ]
jaxws-rt-2.1EA1.jar
class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl [9033 bytes, jvm >= 1.5 ]
jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar
jaxws-rt-2.1.3.jar

Comment: @user2079954 - if this response provided the response to your question, please mark it as answer so it can help others as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exact reason why it can not find the right class but I think it is some problem with (or feature of) Java class loader in **Oracle database** when it looks for resources.

I loaded JAX-WS reference implementation from java.net with all its dependencies with the SYS user (with the public access permissions and public synonyms). But the classes generated from service WSDL I loaded to user SCOTT schema. And for some reason when SCOTT runs procedures that uses service, `javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder` does look up for implementation name in `META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` resource (which have correct value `com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`) but can not find this resource so tries to load provider from hard-coded class name (`com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl`) and fails.

Solution for me was to load all `META-INF/services/*` files from all the JAX-WS RI and dependencies jar's to SCOTT schema. Alternative way could be to load all JAX-WS RI, dependencies **and** final program to the same schema.